# force a uinavigation controller to portrait only

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have the following code inside viewWillAppear:

```
 if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
      UIViewController *mVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
      [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
      [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO ];
      mVC=nil;
   }
```

The problem is that, the methods from the buttom of the xib are not being fired. What I ve notices is the fact that the AppDelegate method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//some code
}
```

is fired. how to solve this?

Comment: Landscape init, push in a new viewController with `OrientationPortrait`?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: I just want to understand your answer, why about AppDelegate and touchesBegan ?

Comment: I have a tabBarController with item1 and item2. When navigatin from item2 (which i put in landscape) to item1 which is set to be in portrait (and fires in portrait correctly), inside UIViewController the last 2 buttons from the xib are not working. The tabBarController is designed and initialized in AppDelegate method

Comment: I ve modified the UINavigation from tabBarController to fire the item1 in portrait, if iOS is in landscape mode. things seem to work ok, except the fact that the last 2 buttons from the bottom of the screen and above the tabBar do not work

Comment: I did tried to put [self.view brindSubviewToFront _button9], but no changes:(

Comment: the CustomTabBarController extends a UITabBarController

Comment: try move buttons up from the bottom, does it work? If not, may be the problem in buttons'superView.

Comment: I found this link which seem to solve my issue. But there is a small flip (animation) from landscape to portait http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886900/disable-rotation-for-one-uitabbar-item. Is there a way i can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue and searched lots of pages, lots of idea on how to move the frame of view and navigation bar back to expected position. While I think it should not be expected by UIKit design.

I found interesting comments by @Romain here that override orientation related, and I think it is should be possible, because the height of navigation bar default to 64 with portrait orientation on iPhone, while it is 44 when rotate to landscape orientation and status bar is hidden in this case. It is the case happen to me.

That means some condition caused the navigation bar treat the case of landscape with status bar hidden, while actually it is not, the design of UIKit is not robust enough to make it right when you override the orientation method incorrectly.

My wrong code caused over lapped is as below.
1. Extension navigation

```
@implementation UINavigationController(shouldAutorotate)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
 return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

@end
```

2. Override orientation methods in ViewController

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

The code caused the overlapped issue, and after I re-orgnaized it again as below, it can works good.
1. Extension navigation controller

```
@implementation UINavigationController(shouldAutorotate)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

@end
```

2. override method for view controller if need to fix orientation to portrait.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The environment I tested is in iOS8.1.2. Pasted it here is because I surfed several hour and not able to find a good solution but many workarounds, and thanks for Romain given the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell your UINavigationController that it must only support portrait orientations. Override the following methods in your view controller implementation:

On iOS 7:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

If you are on iOS 6, also add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: I did had those methds in my code. The issue that i have has this methids included in the code